# How to unmount a formerly chroot'd filesystem?

Tags: mount, chroot, unmounting

I'm using a rescue-live-system (similar to a live-cd) to fix some issues with my Debian server, like that:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/rescue
# mount /dev/md2 /mnt/rescue
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/rescue/dev/
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/rescue/proc/
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/rescue/sys/
```

Now I can chroot to `/mnt/rescue` - but after I'm done, how to unmount the filesystem again?

```
umount: /mnt/rescue: target is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

I guess it's because `dev`, `proc` and `sys` are bound to the mounted file system. But it's not possible to unmount them either...

Comment: What happens when you try to unmount `/mnt/rescue/proc`? Are you sure you don't still have processes running in that `chroot`?

Comment: Try `lsof /mnt/rescue` to see what process is using that folder.

Comment: You need to leave the chrooted shell before shutting down.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. You have to first exit the chroot session, usually a simple `exit` will do:

   ```
   exit
   ```
2. Then umount ALL binded directories:

   ```
   umount /mnt/rescue/dev/
   umount /mnt/rescue/proc/
   umount /mnt/rescue/sys/
   ```
3. Then:

   ```
   umount /mnt/rescue
   ```

---

In case you were worried that `sync` isn't used here, note that it has no influence on whether unmounting is possible. Unmounting flushes pending writes anyway (it has to, because there'd be nowhere for them to go after the unmounting). The presence of a chrooted process is irrelevant (except in that it prevents unmounting). In normal system operation, sync has no observable effect. sync only makes a difference if a device is physically disconnected without having been unmounted or if the system crashes while the device is mounted.

Comment: thanks, that's it... my mistake was trying to unmount /sys/ instead of /mnt/rescue/sys/ ...

Comment: The `sync` is totally useless.

Comment: @Gilles Can you elaborate abit more why `sync` is useless? Does it become useless in current kernel? Or only in this case(rescue mode)? I put it there just in case there are huge pending write to disk that will prevent umount after exiting chroot.

Comment: @JohnSiu `sync` has no influence on whether unmounting is possible. Unmounting flushes pending writes anyway (it has to, because there'd be nowhere for them to go after the unmounting). The presence of a chrooted process is irrelevant (except in that it prevents unmounting). In normal system operation, `sync` has no observable effect. `sync` only makes a difference if a device is physically disconnected without having been unmounted or if the system crashes while the device is mounted.

Comment: @Gilles I understand your point now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 20):

Execute the below command to force and Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.

```
umount -lf /mnt/rescue
```

Comment: there's no comment here regarding the nested mounts.  does this clean them up safely?  can you unmount a filesystem contianing a chroot after this, if all processes have terminated?

Comment: Be careful with this one when using recursive mounts, e.g: `--rbind`. Subsequent recursive mounts of `/sys` and `/dev` don't mount the entire tree!

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you get the 'target is busy.' message is because the mount point (`/mnt/rescue`) is open in a file browser or in a terminal session, and also the order of unmounting process (here I mean `dev/pts` should be umounted before `dev/` )

Well, in order to successfully umount all fs there :

- Make sure the mountpoint isn't open in a file browser!
- After exiting chroot change directory out of chroot dir (`cd`)!
- Umount fs respecting the order `dev/pts => dev/ => proc/ => sys/` :

  sudo umount /mnt/rescue/dev/pts
  sudo umount /mnt/rescue/dev
  sudo umount /mnt/rescue/proc
  sudo umount /mnt/rescue/sys
  sudo umount /mnt/rescue

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do with `schroot` command on Ubuntu version 10.04 upward:

```
# list all sessions:
schroot --list --all-sessions
# if the above command does not work, just type `mount`. The bind mount
# points with something like this in the mount path is the session name you want to get:
precise-a4aac8e0-663c-4fec-8fb2-16e4b06557e3 (<chroot_name>-<id>)

# now run this to properly end the session:
schroot -e -c precise-ca6c72e4-0e9f-4721-8a0e-cca359e2c2fd
```

Comment: perfect thx! on the `schroot --help` "-c [ --chroot ] arg   Use specified chroot" it should actually read: "-c [ --chroot ] arg  Use specified chroot SESSION"! ubuntu 20.04 here

Comment: @AquariusPower in 2020, wonder why docker doesn’t work for you :-?

Comment: do you think docker could work for a i386 install that can be integrated on the running X server? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274951/how-to-successfully-install-wine-with-win32-i386-support-on-ubuntu-20-0

Comment: @AquariusPower I don’t know how far you want to go with schroot and docker, but this might be helpful: [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)

Comment: cool thx! I would have to read more but it seems to run a new X server (inside current one?) but the main point would be security. What I am doing I dont really know if it is as safe as x11docker approach, but what I am doing looks more integrated (like the app looks to be running not from a chroot at all). The whole point, in the end, will be if the applications I want to run will properly run on x11docker as well as I believe they will with schroot (as I havent been able to fully test it yet xD).

Answer (score 0):

Exit chroot.
In the host system, the command 'mount' will show all the mounted path. (Includes those path which are mounted in chroot.)
For example:

```
binfmt_misc on /home/user/projects/jsroot/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

Then enter chroot environment.
In chroot environment run unmount to unmount all path in order. (Sub path must be unmount before parent path.)

```
unmount /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
unmount /proc/sys
unmount /proc
```

Comment: ...and if they refuse to unmount, and you're not in the directory... ?